# Decimal Field Issue in Hive Parquet table

Tags: hive, apache-pig, parquet

I have a parquet table in hive with a field of type

```
decimal (10,2)
```

Now when I am reading this table in pig using `parquet.pig.ParquetLoader` , `decimal field is getting converted to bytearray and giving junk values`.
Is there any solution to this issue?

Comment: While loading the data can you specify the field type as double or bigdecimal ?

Comment: I can not change the business schema Murali and when we load a parquet file in pig, we don't specify schema. Its already present in the parquet file metadata.

Comment: which version of hive are you using?

Comment: I don't remember the hive version.. But its the latest one .. With cloudera 5.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have written a cusotom ParquetLoader in which we extended LoadFunc class and implemented the cases we wanted for handling decimal.